# Is this white thing correct in kriek lambic?

Tags: contamination, lambics

I'm making my first lambic beer, a kriek lambic with a one month old, last week I dropped 1lb cherries. Today, I noticed this white thing in top:

[image: White and weird bug]

Should I concern about this? Or just let it go...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what a lambic is all about!  That's the pellicle forming.  Completely normal.

Comment: Aright, thanks... I'll leave my beer do whatever it wants to do a long while

Comment: Not too long, I've found that lambics have the shortest shelf-life, and can get over-bitter.

Comment: How long is enough?